# Loading the information from a 2D-Array in a class so it can be used in the main class. C# Wpf

Tags: c#, arrays, load

I just started with c# and I'm sure this information can be found with some googling, however I have no idea what to search for to find a relevant answer.

I have a 2D-array containing a bunch of information as a database, I put this in a separate class under a function (or method, I don't know the correct term), called GetDB.

So in my main class I entered (Da_Ba is the name of the class) "Da_Ba my_database = new Da_Ba();"  right after the  "public partial class MainWindow : Window {"-part

Later on, on the click of a button, I'm trying to read information from the array...
the name of the array is db_array, and it's 2-dimensional, and here's where I think I went wrong.
I did it like this:
variable1 = my_database.db_array[0,1];

The error returned is "'WpfApplication1.Da_Ba' does not contain a definition for 'db_array' and no extension method 'db_array' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication1.Da_Ba' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Both the main class and the added class have the same namespace.
The array is declared in the class as int[,] db_array = new int[100,10];
And a value is assigned to db_array[0,1] in the class.

Does someone know how to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

This is the class:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
       {
       class Da_Ba
       {
       public void GetDB()
       {
       int[,] db_array = new int[100, 10];
       db_array[0, 1] = 10;
       }}}
```

This is the Main thingy, where I declare other variables:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Da_Ba my_database = new Da_Ba();
    }
```

And this is how I'm trying to read it from a button:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        variable1 = my_database.db_array[0, 1];
    }
```

I want variable1 to be set to 10, but to read that information from a 2d-array in another class.

Comment: Could you post some code please so we can better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"'WpfApplication1.Da_Ba' does not contain a definition for 'db_array' and no extension method 'db_array' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication1.Da_Ba' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

This error is given because you defined your db_array Array in GetDB function. You should define it in Da_Ba Class.I think the error is because this.

you should do that like :

```
 namespace WpfApplication1
       {
       class Da_Ba
       {
       public int[,] db_array; 
       public void GetDB()
       {
       db_array = new int[100, 10];
       db_array[0, 1] = 10;
       }}}
```

and in your mainwindow class you should call your getDB() function to initialize your array

Comment: It works wonders, thank you. This is exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Db_array is declared in a function and not in the da_ba class.
I recommed you to read more about classes and properties